# Multiple rows in input field

Tags: field

```
<center><label for="max">Message:</label><input type="text" name="message" value="This is the message" +message=""></center><br>
```

How can I make the input field a bit bigger with many rows?

Also, I want the "This is the message" to be like a label so when the user clicks in there he can type anything he wants instead of this text.

Comment: Simple input field can’t have multiple rows. You want a `textarea` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTML input to have multiple lines, you would need to make use of the textarea element.

To answer the other part of the question, I think it would depend on the HTML version you making use of, you could use 'placeholder' instead of 'value' attribute to have a placeholder text.

```
    <center><label for="max">Message:</label><textarea name="message" placeholder="This is the message" +message=""></textarea><br>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to increase size of your text box?
Using style you cant increse size of your text box
`<center><label for="max">Message:</label><input type="text" name="message" value="This is the message" +message="" style="width:100%"></center><br>`